# Docker for Windows can not Connect to git Container registry

Tags: git, docker, deployment, windows-10, registry

**Scenario:**
I developed a Microservice Architecture with Spring and now I want to deploy it with docker on an external Linux headless vm.
My Host System is Windows 10 and I use Docker for Windows.

**My Intention:**
I want to push my Images to our local git lab registry running in a local domain Network and pull them from within the target vm running on an external server.

**Problem:**
I can not connect to the repository with

```
docker login IP:Port
```

from my host system.
The Error I get is

> Error response from daemon: Get http://ip:port/v2/: net/http:
> request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded
> while awaiting headers)

But I can ping the ip successfully which brings me to the point that my Network Connection is fine.
I can also download and run the hello-world image from docker hub.
The connection from the vm with the same command and URL works. I only had to enable `insecure registry` in the deamon.json file.

**Steps tried to solve the problem:**
First I tried to setup docker with docker toolbox.
This resulted in the same error.
After that I moved from the docker toolbox to docker desktop which resulted in the described error.
I also added the insecure registry entry. Not working either.
A colleague of mine is working on the same repository but with a Ubuntu host machine.
His setup with the same commands works fine.
I never worked with docker before so the error could be pretty simple but after digging for 2 days I really can't find a reason for this strange behavior.
Thanks in advance

**UPDATE:**
I had a problem to create a virtual switch in hyper-V for my Docker vm.
After dis/enable the hyper V network adapter in my Device Manager I was able to register a new external virtual switch. But now I got the following message when I want to login:

> Error response from daemon: Get http://myrepo:1234/v2/: dial tcp:
> lookup mypreo on 193.163.72.1:34: read udp
> 193.163.72.3:34::58297->193.163.72.1:34: i/o timeout

I haven't researched in detail yet but I look lika a DNS problem?

**Additional Information:**
Docker Version: Docker version 18.09.1
Windows: Windows 10 Enterprise 64 Bit

Docker Settings:
Advanced:
CPUs:2
Memory:2048 MB
Swap: 1024 MB
Disk Image max size: 64 GB (0 B used)

Network:
Internal Virtual Switch:
Subnet Address : 10.0.75.0 (default)
Subnet Mask:     255.255.255.0

DNS Server:
Automatic

Proxies:
No proxy

Daemon:
Experimental features enabled
Insecure registries:
ip:Port of registry

Comment: have you enabled gitlab container registry ?

Comment: Is there something ele to enable on my local machine?
We have this feature running in our gitlab so you can see this feature when you login and there is a user manual how to deploy and push your Docker images.
At the moment I think it is a problem with my Hyper-V ethernet switch.
When I create one my internet crashes. No matter if I use lan or wifi. 
At the beginning it was not even possible to create a switch but aber dis- and enableing the hyper-V network adapter, is worked again.

Comment: If you could ping to the destination it shouldn't be a network problem. When you install docker for windows it creates hyper-v virtual adapter, so network, automatically. Unless you did something different.

Comment: Yeah it's the dockerNAT adapter?
The settings of this adapter is set to local. Doesn't it need to be external and briged to my lan or wlan network adapter?

Comment: dockerNat should be internal. It resolves the network from the virtual switch created by hyper-v. By using NAT it provides access to the your computers network. You can see it from Hyper-V Manager.

Comment: Ok so I have my docker running in the MobyLinuxVm. My switches are Layered_vEthernet(wlanswitch) which is set to private and de DockerNat which is set to intern. In the Settings of the VM I use DockerNAT as Networkadapter.
So with config docker should be able to connect to git running in a local domain network?

Comment: if that doesn't work can you try switching 'wlanswitch's connection type to internal?

Comment: No, doesn't work either. I can ping the machine but when I try to do de docker login commant, I get the describes error response from daemon.
I testet it with DockerNat as Networkadapter internal und wlanswitch as private and internal.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem on centos7.9. It was solved when I added "ip dns" in `/etc/hosts`, so maybe you could find the same function in windows to solve it.